# Which chapters of Sayonara Zetsubou Sensei manga are animated?

Tags: sayonara-zetsubou-sensei

I'd like to know which chapters are not in anime, so I could read just them in-between watching episodes, so the whole experience would be in manga release order.

I've seen [this marvelous Google Spreadsheet for Nisekoi](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1OPZh2OepUEqUR62CgkfU52Ja_ry2cxM0kUdhXJwMhJ8/htmlview#gid=0) and ideally an answer with something like this would be the best.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to [Japanese Wikipedia](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E3%81%95%E3%82%88%E3%81%AA%E3%82%89%E7%B5%B6%E6%9C%9B%E5%85%88%E7%94%9F_(%E3%82%A2%E3%83%8B%E3%83%A1)#.E5.90.84.E8.A9.B1.E3.83.AA.E3.82.B9.E3.83.88),

> *Sayonara Zetsubou Sensei* (1st season):
>
> 1. Chapter 1, 2, 8
> 2. Chapter 3, 4, 8
> 3. Chapter 6, 9
> 4. Chapter 5, 7
> 5. Chapter 45, 42
> 6. Chapter 17, 18
> 7. Chapter 15, 26
> 8. Chapter 14, 19
> 9. Chapter 27, 28
> 10. Chapter 23, 22, 24
> 11. Chapter 53, 33, 29, anime original
> 12. Chapter 55, 46
>
> *Zoku Sayonara Zetsubou Sensei* (2nd season):
>
> 1. Volume 1 + recap, chapter 10
> 2. Chapter 12, 85, 50
> 3. Chapter 74, 71, 90
> 4. Chapter 100, 22, 100
> 5. Chapter 68, 35, 98
> 6. Chapter 13, 47, 97
> 7. Chapter 54, (end of Volume 5, 9, 10 + anime original), chapter 36
> 8. Chapter 107, 94, 65
> 9. Chapter 34, 108, anime original
> 10. Chapter 106, 113, 111
> 11. Anime original, chapter 11
> 12. Chapter 99, 78, 51
> 13. Chapter 81, 112, 52
>
> *Goku Sayonara Zetsubou Sensei* (1st OVA/2.5th season):
>
> - Top: Chapter 126, 109, 70
> - Annotation (Middle): Chapter 138, 150, 69
> - Bottom: Chapter 149, 130, anime original
>
> *Zan Sayonara Zetsubou Sensei* (3rd season):
>
> 1. Chapter 126, 134, 103
> 2. Chapter 154, 129, 103
> 3. Chapter 163, 96, 104
> 4. Chapter 141, 145, 104
> 5. Chapter 174, 166, 105
> 6. Chapter 128, 157, 105
> 7. Chapter 158, 83, 153
> 8. Chapter 153, 165, 160
> 9. Chapter 124, 172, 169
> 10. Chapter 176, 156, 169
> 11. Chapter 86, 183, 159
> 12. Chapter 170, 178, 183, end of Volume 15
> 13. Chapter 187, 179, *bangai-hen*
>
> *Zan Sayonara Zetsubou Sensei Bangai-chi* (2nd OVA/3.5th season):
>
> 1. Top: Chapter 136, 184, 190
> 2. Bottom: Chapter 181, 193, 140
>
> *Zan Sayonara Zetsubou Sensei* (Blu-ray BOX Commemoration):
>
> 1. Top: Anime original, chapter 231
> 2. Bottom: End of Volume 24

---

Recompiling the list to show the corresponding episodes to the manga chapters:

- Chapter 1: S1E1
- Chapter 2: S1E1
- Chapter 3: S1E2
- Chapter 4: S1E2
- Chapter 5: S1E4
- Chapter 6: S1E3
- Chapter 7: S1E4
- Chapter 8: S1E1, S1E2
- Chapter 9: S1E3
- Chapter 10: S2E1
- Chapter 11: S2E11
- Chapter 12: S2E2
- Chapter 13: S2E6
- Chapter 14: S1S8
- Chapter 15: S1E7
- Chapter 17: S1E6
- Chapter 18: S1E6
- Chapter 19: S1S8
- Chapter 22: S1E10, S2E4
- Chapter 23: S1E10
- Chapter 24: S1E10
- Chapter 26: S1E7
- Chapter 27: S1S9
- Chapter 28: S1S9
- Chapter 29: S1E11
- Chapter 33: S1E11
- Chapter 34: S2E9
- Chapter 35: S2E5
- Chapter 36: S2E7
- Chapter 42: S1E5
- Chapter 45: S1E5
- Chapter 46: S1E12
- Chapter 47: S2E6
- Chapter 50: S2E2
- Chapter 51: S2E12
- Chapter 52: S2E13
- Chapter 53: S1E11
- Chapter 54: S2E7
- Chapter 55: S1E12
- Chapter 65: S2E8
- Chapter 68: S2E5
- Chapter 69: O1E2
- Chapter 70: O1E1
- Chapter 71: S2E3
- Chapter 74: S2E3
- Chapter 78: S2E12
- Chapter 81: S2E13
- Chapter 83: S3E7
- Chapter 85: S2E2
- Chapter 86: S3E11
- Chapter 90: S2E3
- Chapter 94: S2E8
- Chapter 96: S3E3
- Chapter 97: S2E6
- Chapter 98: S2E5
- Chapter 99: S2E12
- Chapter 100: S2E4, S2E4
- Chapter 103: S3E1, S3E2
- Chapter 104: S3E3, S3E4
- Chapter 105: S3E5, S3E6
- Chapter 106: S2E10
- Chapter 107: S2E8
- Chapter 108: S2E9
- Chapter 109: O1E1
- Chapter 111: S2E10
- Chapter 112: S2E13
- Chapter 113: S2E10
- Chapter 124: S3E9
- Chapter 126: O1E1, S3E1
- Chapter 128: S3E6
- Chapter 129: S3E2
- Chapter 130: O1E3
- Chapter 134: S3E1
- Chapter 136: O2E1
- Chapter 138: O1E2
- Chapter 140: O2E2
- Chapter 141: S3E4
- Chapter 145: S3E4
- Chapter 149: O1E3
- Chapter 150: O1E2
- Chapter 153: S3E7, S3E8
- Chapter 154: S3E2
- Chapter 156: S3E10
- Chapter 157: S3E6
- Chapter 158: S3E7
- Chapter 159: S3E11
- Chapter 160: S3E8
- Chapter 163: S3E3
- Chapter 165: S3E8
- Chapter 166: S3E5
- Chapter 169: S3E9, S3E10
- Chapter 170: S3E12
- Chapter 172: S3E9
- Chapter 174: S3E5
- Chapter 176: S3E10
- Chapter 178: S3E12
- Chapter 179: S3E13
- Chapter 181: O2E2
- Chapter 183: S3E11, S3E12
- Chapter 184: O2E1
- Chapter 187: S3E13
- Chapter 190: O2E1
- Chapter 193: O2E2
- Chapter 231: BD-E1
- Volume 1: S2E1
- End of Volume 5, 9, 10: S2E7
- End of Volume 15: S3E12
- End of Volume 24: BD-E2
- *Bangai-hen*: S3E12, S3E12

Comment: I... personally wouldn't recommend to watch the anime in manga order since it's FUBAR...